# Has anyone used the quincunx dilation matrix to form compactly supported wavelet functions?

Tags: reference-request, wavelets

Has anyone used the quincunx dilation matrix to form compactly supported wavelet functions? I know that it's possible, in fact a lot of references make the analog of the Harr wavelet basis, but I'm thinking something more general. Most references seem to say that it's too complicated, and they prefer using a different dilation matrix for two-dimensional wavelet functions. (ex: http://www.math.wustl.edu/~krishtal/papers/krww.pdf at the bottom of page 1)

Also - are there general conditions on the coefficients of the dilation equation in two dimensions to form an MRA?